# How to upload my works to Thingiverse without making my real name public

Tags: makerbot, 3d-models

I want to upload some of my works to [Thingiverse](http://www.thingiverse.com/) without making my real name public (displaying it on the profile page).

I think it is OK to register my name to the site unless the make it public, and it is required by the terms to provide truthful and accurate information.

I tried creating an account on the site, but I deleted it because I couldn't find the way to hide my name (set another one) from the profile page in a short time.

I see some accounts that doesn't seem showing their real name (for example, their name on profile equals to their account ID, or at least not in two parts: first and last name as required on registration), so I guess this is archivable.

examples:

- http://www.thingiverse.com/Darkcheops/about
- http://www.thingiverse.com/ruaridh/about
- https://www.thingiverse.com/Torleif/about

How can I set my name for profile page on Thingiverse after registration and logging in?

Comment: Maybe I should use [YouMagine](https://www.youmagine.com/) or [makershop.co](https://www.makershop.co/), which don't seem asking my first & last name, to share my works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change your displayed name (as opposed to username) in Thingiverse:

1. Go to your profile page
2. Click "Edit Profile" on the info column on the left
3. At the top, next to "Thingiverse Settings" is another link/tab called "Makerbot Settings". Click that.
4. Change the First Name and Last Name fields, and save.

Note that neither First nor Last Name is required; if neither is provided, your username will be displayed in place of your display name.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I thought making them blank is impossible because they said First & Last names are required on registration.

Comment: I joined this community just to +1.  It makes sense that Makebot would put this setting into a place that people least expect, since the company is not exactly integral to the community anymore.

Comment: If editing, beware that true anonymity is achieved: your public profile will have been indexed by Google etc, and the case of Google can be revealed by "View Cached Page" in their search results.

Answer (score 4):

You can put whatever name you want in when you make an account - You decide what your name is, people go by pseudonyms in 'real life' all the time, this is perfectly acceptable. There are actually very few places where you have a legal obligation to provide your name as it appears on your birth certificate. Opening a Thingiverse account is not one of them.

To answer the other part of your question, yes, it is possible to change the name displayed after you have created your account. I would be surprised if they bother to actually keep an archive of past names though.

Comment: Yes, but the point of his question is it's totally non-intuitive where to locate this setting. It's "hidden" under "Makerbot settings", a place I would never ever look since I do not have a Makerbot device.